# How to Store Old pic in Database if no new image Updated In php

Tags: php, image

hi in my form when user submit the form and select no image then my database updated blank can you help me where is wrong in the code I don't have PHP knowledge so need your help

here is my Full PHP code hope you got it where is this wrong

i want if user not select image then old image does not replace with blank

i try in my code my still got blank!

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $form_no = $_POST['form_no'];
        $shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];
        $shop_address = $_POST['shop_address'];
        $owner_name = $_POST['owner_name'];
        $owner_address = $_POST['owner_address'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $m_no = $_POST['m_no'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $d_o_b = $_POST['d_o_b'];
        $d_o_m = $_POST['d_o_m'];
        $b_type = $_POST['b_type'];
        $reg_no = $_POST['reg_no'];
        $coment = $_POST['coment'];
        $date = date('y-m-d');
        $errors = "";
        $plan = $_POST['select'];
        $oldpic=$_POST["oldpic"];
        if($_FILES['image']['name'] != "" && $errors == "")
        {
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
            $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
            if(!in_array($file_ext,$expensions))
            {
                $errors="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
            }

            if($file_size > 2097152)
            {
                $errors ='File size must be excately 2 MB';
            }
            if(empty($errors))
            {
                $new_file_name = uniqid().'.'.$file_ext;
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user/".$new_file_name);
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors))
        {
            $qreury = "UPDATE members SET 
            ref_no='$ref_no',shop_name='$shop_name', form_no='$form_no',
            shop_address='$shop_address', owner_name='$owner_name',
            owner_address='$owner_address', tel_no='$phone', mobile_no='$m_no',
            email='$email',dob='$d_o_b',marrige_date='$d_o_m',bussiness_type='$b_type',
            reg_no='$reg_no',extra_note='$coment',user_pic='$new_file_name',
            plan='$plan',target=(select price from members_plan where id ='$plan') WHERE id='$id'";
            $reslt = mysql_query($qreury)or die(mysql_error());
            header("location:registered_members.php");

        }
    elseif(empty($oldpic))
        {
            $qreury = "UPDATE members SET 
            ref_no='$ref_no',shop_name='$shop_name', form_no='$form_no',
            shop_address='$shop_address', owner_name='$owner_name',
            owner_address='$owner_address', tel_no='$phone', mobile_no='$m_no',
            email='$email',dob='$d_o_b',marrige_date='$d_o_m',bussiness_type='$b_type',
            reg_no='$reg_no',extra_note='$coment',user_pic='$oldpic',
            plan='$plan',target=(select price from members_plan where id ='$plan') WHERE id='$id'";
            $reslt = mysql_query($qreury)or die(mysql_error());
            header("location:registered_members.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your response check again I update my full code!

Comment: Before going any further, you should refactor your code using Mysqli or PDO and with Prepared Statements. It's just a waste of time to knowingly fix insecure and out dated code that will need to be rewritten anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, Please let Your code do what its doing. Even if you are storing null then don't worry. Store the null and put an avtar default image on your file system, and then You can do the following while fetching the image to view it for you:

```
    <img src="
<?php !empty($your-image-with-directory)?$your-image-with-directory:"upload-directory/avtar.png"?>" width="100">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     {
if(empty($_FILES))   {
$error="Please select a photo to continue";
break;
}
    $reg_no = $_POST['reg_no'];
        $coment = $_POST['coment'];
        $date = date('y-m-d');
        $errors = "";
        $plan = $_POST['select'];
        $oldpic=$_POST["oldpic"];
        if($_FILES['image']['name'] != "" && $errors == "")
        {
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
            $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
            if(!in_array($file_ext,$expensions))
            {
                $errors="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
            }

            if($file_size > 2097152)
            {
                $errors ='File size must be excately 2 MB';
            }
            if(empty($errors))
            {
                $new_file_name = uniqid().'.'.$file_ext;
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user/".$new_file_name);
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors))
        {
            $qreury = "UPDATE members SET 
            ref_no='$ref_no',shop_name='$shop_name', form_no='$form_no',
            shop_address='$shop_address', owner_name='$owner_name',
            owner_address='$owner_address', tel_no='$phone', mobile_no='$m_no',
            email='$email',dob='$d_o_b',marrige_date='$d_o_m',bussiness_type='$b_type',
            reg_no='$reg_no',extra_note='$coment',user_pic='$new_file_name',
            plan='$plan',target=(select price from members_plan where id ='$plan') WHERE id='$id'";
            $reslt = mysql_query($qreury)or die(mysql_error());
            header("location:registered_members.php");

            }
        elseif(empty($oldpic))
            {
                $qreury = "UPDATE members SET 
                ref_no='$ref_no',shop_name='$shop_name', form_no='$form_no',
                shop_address='$shop_address', owner_name='$owner_name',
                owner_address='$owner_address', tel_no='$phone', mobile_no='$m_no',
                email='$email',dob='$d_o_b',marrige_date='$d_o_m',bussiness_type='$b_type',
                reg_no='$reg_no',extra_note='$coment',user_pic='$oldpic',
                plan='$plan',target=(select price from members_plan where id ='$plan') WHERE id='$id'";
                $reslt = mysql_query($qreury)or die(mysql_error());
                header("location:registered_members.php");
            }
        }

        }while(0);
```

Replace your code with mine it will work

Comment: A good answer includes an _explanation_. Why should the OP use your code? What have you changed? How does it solve the issue? Don't let the OP, and all future visitors, guess.

Comment: You should also verify your code. Just copy/pasting this would result in errors. Btw, what's up with the `while(0)`?

Comment: @Shahid Muneer your code force user to select image while i want to if no image select then old store image save as is it please check i update full code

Comment: Magnus Eriksson this while will allow only executing the code for one time, we can break the execution while on way easily.

Comment: well if you don't want to force user to upload a picture than you keep the default null and where you are rendering the image <img src="your-sorce-upload-directory/default-image "

Comment: I have given an alternative answer if it doesn't feel better there is another way of storing a default image also.